# How to compare List<string> with data in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
        string searchByTags = "politics, economy";
        char[] delimiters = new[] { ',', ';', ' ', '#' };  // List of your delimiters
        List<string> providedTags = null;
        if (searchByTags != null)
        {
            providedTags = searchByTags.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }

        ViewNotesVM vnVM = new ViewNotesVM();
        vnVM.Quotes = db.SavedQuotes.Where(s => s.Tags.Any(x => (searchByTags != null) ? providedTags.Any(y => y == x.Name) : true)).ToList();
```

All "SavedQuotes" have some "Tags". This is simple class called "Tag" that has "Name" property. It is stored in SavedQuotes as ICollection.

What I want to do, is to display all "SavedQuotes" from database, that have tags given in "searchByTags" variable.

But there is some problem in my code. Visual Studio shows an error:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

What's wrong with my code and how can I do it better?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is simplify your query and so that it can be translated into SQL. Also, you should split it in two separate queries for the two separate cases you are trying to address:

1. Filtering by a set of tags
2. Not filtering if no tags were provided.

You could do that like this:

```
private static readonly _emptyTags = new List<string>();

// ...

// Get list with applicable tags.
List<string> providedTags = (searchByTags != null)
    ? providedTags = searchByTags.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    : _emptyTags;

// ...

// Split based on whether any tags were provided as a filter.
if (providedTags.Length > 0)
{
    // Filter by tags
    vnVM.Quotes = db.SavedQuotes
        .Where(s => s.Tags.Any(t => providedTags.Contains(t.Name)))
        .ToList();
}
else 
{
    // Get them all
    vnVM.Quotes = db.SavedQuotes.ToList(); // note: unbounded result set.
}
```